# Compile native c binaries for Android - Eg: dosfsck

Tags: android, compilation, executable

I am trying to compile the binary dosfsck and mkdosfs for Android, using Linux and Android NDK and SDK. I've setup NDK and SDK properly, the path to the NDK gcc is in my path. I've also downloaded the correct SDK for my device (HTC Desire).

I first tried compiling the file with a simple make:

> make
>   CROSS_COMPILE=/home/droidzone/android/android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

I need to be able to run the binary from my device. As it is, the app compiles and runs on Ubuntu, but not my device. I get the error message from sh: Cannot run binary

Could someone please explain how I can link libraries, where I should get them from (within the SDK) and what changes if any to make to the Makefile, and the final syntax to compile this properly for Android

Answer (score 0):

I found this was easiest to do using the [agcc script](http://plausible.org/andy/agcc) script which you can use by exporting CC=agcc. Lots of projects will not properly support CROSS_COMPILE as you have tried. The agcc script is oriented around using the Android build tree files so I modified it [to use the NDK tools](http://www.patthoyts.tk/tclkit/android-arm/agcc-ndk). With this you should be able to build most things using `make CC=agcc` or `CC=agcc ./configure`

Comment: Thanks...but the agcc script gave me a lot of errors.. I dont understand the folder parent "BIONIC" that it seems to refer to...

Comment: Some mild editing of the paths in the script needs to be done to make is compatible with your system. Basically anywhere you don't see the full path add in your full path to the same resource.